# Nilpotent matrices and similarity.

Tags: linear-algebra

True or false:

Let $A,B\in M_5(\mathbb{C})$. $A$ and $B$ are similar **iff** they have same nilpotent index.

One direction is clear, but the second is not true, right?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the nilpotent index? Is the smallest natural number $k$ such that $A^k=0_{n\times n}$? If it is, how do you define the nilpotent index in case such a $k$ doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The converse is not true in general. Just take two non-zero nilpotent matrices $A$ and $B$ in different canonical Jordan form with $A^2=B^2=0$:
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 &0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
\end{pmatrix}, \quad 
B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \cr
       0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \cr
\end{pmatrix}
$$